# Case para vários campos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Consigo fazer uma `query` utilizando 1 `case` para vários campos? Os campos são do tipo `int`.

Caso não, consigo fazer em php?

**Query**

```
select *,
(case (pergunta1,pergunta2)
when 1 then 'Ótimo'
when 2 then 'Bom'
when 3 then 'Regular'
when 4 then 'Ruim'                                                            
END) as pergunta1,pergunta2 from tabela
```

Comment: Não faria o BD retornar textos dessa forma, seria inviável trabalhar com pacotes de tradução, manutenção... Joga isso num `array` em *PHP*, muito mais simples.

Comment: Seria isso? `$arr = array('', 'Ótimo', 'Bom', 'Regular', 'Ruim');`
`echo $arr[$pergunta1];`

Comment: Sim, só remova o índice vazio: `$arr = array(1 => 'Ótimo', 2 => 'Bom', 3 => 'Regular', 4=>  'Ruim');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, porém pra utilizar esse tipo de `case` você não pode ter o valor fixo logo após o `case` e os testes devem ser realizados no `when` da seguinte forma:

```
select *,
      (case
         when pergunta1 = 1 and pergunta2 = 1 then 'Ótimo'
         when pergunta1 = 2 and pergunta2 = 2 then 'Bom'
         when pergunta1 = 3 and pergunta2 = 3 then 'Regular'
         when pergunta1 = 4 and pergunta2 = 4 then 'Ruim'
      END) as pergunta1,pergunta2 from tabela
```